# Determine new rows in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

In Python I have a SQlite database with table containing a list of events.

Columns :

```
EventName 
StartDate 
EndDate   
DateAdded
```

The same events can be added to the table on multiple days.  The table is refreshed once per day.

I need to determine on a daily basis if there are any new events by comparing the events added on the current day with the events added on previous days.

I suppose I can write SQL to achieve this :

```
SELECT e.EventName ,
       e.StartDate ,
       e.EndDate   ,
       e.DateAdded
FROM   Events AS e
WHERE  e.DateAdded = '2017-09-13'
       AND NOT EXISTS (   SELECT e2.EventName ,
                                 e2.StartDate ,
                                 e2.EndDate   ,
                                 e2.DateAdded ,
                                 e2.EventName
                          FROM   Events AS e2
                          WHERE  e2.DateAdded < '2017-09-13'
                                 AND e2.EventName = e.EventName
                      );
```

I wondered if there was a way to do this without SQL i.e. using pandas or any other data structure?
Reason I ask is that the code refers to SQL data many times and I was thinking if I can query database once and then operate on the data in-situ then it will be less resource intensive.

Sample Data :

```
EventName   Startdate    EndDate     DateAdded
Liverpool   2017-07-01   2017-07-10  2017-09-01
Manchester  2017-08-01   2017-08-20  2017-09-01
Liverpool   2017-07-01   2017-07-10  2017-09-02
Manchester  2017-08-01   2017-08-20  2017-09-02
London      2017-10-01   2017-10-10  2017-09-02
```

I want to return the last row if running this on 2017-09-02:

```
London      2017-10-01   2017-10-10  2017-09-02
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read your existing SQL table into pandas DataFrame `df` and your new records into DataFrame `new_df`, you can add the concatenate new records with old records using:

```
df = pd.concat([df, new_df])
```

...and then filter `df` to only new rows by flagging all non-unique rows in `df` with `df.duplicated(keep=False)`, and then negating these rows in an index operation:

```
df = df[~df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

`df` will then contain only unique rows (i.e. rows new to your SQL table).